# Can't bind a window method : "Invalid calling object"

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11

I'm trying this on IE 11, but it doesn't work. Is anyone able to explain me why ? I can't found any answer on other threads.

```
var navigatorMsSave = window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob;
navigatorMsSave(new Blob([blob], {type: "application/pdf"}), "File.pdf");
```

**Error code: Invalid calling object**

All of my variables are okay because when I'm starting the code below, all is fine and I can download the correct file.

```
window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(new Blob([blob], {type: "application/pdf"}), "File.pdf");
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you invoke `window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob()` the context (`this` reference) is `navigator`. But when you do `navigatorMsSave()` it's not, it'll be the scope of function you're calling from, or global scope depending on where you're calling it.

You can try

```
var navigatorMsSave = window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob.bind(window.navigator);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your complete answer, I understand it now. The binding is a perfect way to make this work :)